# Proving a sequence contains coprime numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm going through some problems and came across this one that stumped me:

Let $c$ be fixed. Consider the sequence {$a_n$} defined by $a_1 = 1$, and for $n \geq 2$

$a_n = a_{n/2}$ if $n$ is even
$a_n = (3c+1)a_{(n-1)/2}$ if $n$ is odd

Prove that $a_n$ and $c$ are coprime for all $n \in N$

I'm assuming we prove this using induction since we prove this for ALL $n$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: oops sorry, I had them reversed, I fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use induction, but it's not necessary.

Suppose that there is an $r$ for which $a_r$ is not coprime with $c$. Then there will be a smallest such $r$. This will necessarily be odd, since if it were even then since $a_{r/2}=a_r$ we have that $r/2$ would be a smaller number satisfying the condition. But for such odd $r$ we have that 
$$
a_r=(3c+1)a_{(r-1)/2}.
$$ 
Now, if $a_r$ is coprime with $c$, then so is $a_{(r-1)/2}$, since of course $3c+1$ is coprime with $c$. This gives a contradiction.